# What is the reference being made by saying "I did this at a serious seminar once"?

Tags: osadai

In *Osananajimi wa Daitouryou*, there is a comedy scene between the main character, Hondo Jun'ichirou, and Ell. The conversation goes like this:

> **Ell:** A small test. It is a simple CPU inspection. I know.
>
> Ell earnestly nodded, then pulled a mechanical pencil out from her pen case and faced the desk. She then muttered a single sentence.
>
> **Ell:** Ah, I did this at a serious seminar once.
>
> **Jun'ichirou:** What are you blurting out all of a sudden!?
>
> **Ell:** It is a simulation. I heard that your test score will go up if you announce it in this manner.
>
> **Jun'ichirou:** Where are you getting that information from...?
>
> **Ell:** From 7ch.

This is a screenshot of the same scene in Japanese for reference purpose:

[image: Screenshot: あ、これ真剣ゼミでやったことがある]

**What is the reference being made when Ell said "I did this at a serious seminar once"?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, roughly when did this scene occur? I vaguely remember it, but it's been years since I read this so I have no clue where.

Comment: @LoganM: Shortly after the very first bomb scene during the common part.

Answer (score 3):

The [進研ゼミ](http://chu.benesse.co.jp/) (Shinkenzemi) is a one of the most famous distance learning service for minors in Japan.

'真剣' and '進研', both read as 'shinken.'

'真剣' meaning "seriousness"

'ゼミ' is short for "seminar."

'進' means "progress/advancement".

'研' means "sharpen/polish/study."

This is a parody that use similar sounding Japanese characters.

> あ、これ進研ゼミでやったことがある
>
> I did this at the Shinkenzemi once.

Much like McDonald's and MacRonald's in English.

Comment: `for the children` Not sure about "children" - I just saw an article about this service being offered for high school students.

Comment: Sorry, under 20 years old person is called child in Japan. I think this standards or lows are difference of the countries.

Comment: I apologize that my words were not enough.
'I did this at the Shinkenzemi once'. This is a copy of the Shinkenzemi for elementary school.

Comment: I have undeleted your answer, as it does provide an answer to the question. I take it that your concern was that you might have said something wrong (due to the language barrier), or not enough, and that is why you deleted it. However, the answer seems fine to me, and it even has some votes, which means the community also approves of your answer :)

Comment: The reason are the language and the culture barrier. I'd like to explain about the 'child' in Japan, but I have no skill to say suitable English X( So, I deleted it to avoid the misunderstanding. Are there this community has the way to undelete? I'd like to know how to perfection delete.

Comment: @oden There's nothing wrong with your answer. If you have a problem with word/grammar choices between Japanese and English, I will try to help you as best as I can. For an example I believe the word "minor" (未成年者) is more appropriate than "children" in this context.

Comment: @ɹǝzɐɹʞ Thank you very much! I did not know the work 'minor'.

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm sorry about my poor English X(

Comment: @oden you shouldn't that your English is poor, it's still developing, keep at it and you'll get it in no time. (◕‿-)b

Comment: @ɹǝzɐɹʞ Oooohhhh! Your English is more understandable than my English for me! Why!

Comment: @oden You can always visit [our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-) if you need some help! All users are welcome. Also, regarding the undeletion, only moderators and [trusted users](http://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) can do that.

Comment: @JNat You can undelete your own messages.